# Why does protractor not locate element when it's referenced on 2 consecutive lines?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, protractor

If I use the following code in an `it` block in my spec.ts file:

```
    element(by.css(".header-text")).getText().then(function(text) {
        console.log(text);
    });
    expect(element(by.css(".header-text")).getText()).toEqual("Project");
```

I get the following outputted to my console:

```
Project

Expected '' to equal 'Project'.
Expected :"Project"
Actual   :""
```

A few observations with this.

- If I remove the first "line" of code with the console.log, the expect works as expected.
- When I run this code first thing after starting up my machine it works the first 2-3 runs.  Which is weird because protractor starts a new browser each run (I thought and appear to observe) and there shouldn't be some type of caching going on.
- It appears to me that this seems to be some type of "when measured, the value changes" behavior that I really don't expect out of programming, but I'm new to Javascript/Angular/Protractor, so maybe this is just something that happens and you have to have the tribal knowledge that it behaves this way.

This isn't project breaking,  I have my test working the way I want. I would just like an explanation as to why this behavior occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You are already resolving the promise, so you could just use it at the same time.

```
element(by.css(".header-text")).getText()
    .then(function(text) {
        console.log(text);
        expect(text).toEqual("Project");
    });
```

The `expect` method is supposed to resolve promises, but why ask twice if you already have it.

The other thing to check for is anything in your application that will make it look like Angular has done it's job, but then changes the title - as it appears that you may be getting the title before it is populated *in some cases* which suggests a race condition.

Comment: Totally agreed about using it at the same time.  The console.log was more of a debugging step I had done before.  I just found the behavior weird in that it seemed to change behavior depending on when it ran. So clarifying question, is the issue that the first getText is evaluated after the page is loaded (but is made into a promise when the line is reached in code execution), while the second one is done before the page is loaded, but the output is still in code order? Is the first with the console.log evaluated after the second one but printed out first bc of code order?